# How can I enforce a custom order of messages in Pulsar?

Tags: apache-pulsar

I have 2 producers that will send similar messages to the same topic. In this case, one will send a DELETE for a specific ID/Key, the other will send a CREATE for a specific ID/key.

Producer 1:

1. Message #1 Sends DELETE

Producer 2:

2. Message #2 Sends CREATE

Now, I know that #2 came first, but there is no guarantee that they will get to Pulsar in that order.  Sometimes #1 will go before #2 and then the end state is the record exists.

Is there anyway (without a custom process) to have Pulsar setup in a way that it will not run #2 if #1 already ran?  I do have access to a version, so I have an ID that shows that #1 definitely happened after #2, but I don't know how to get Pulsar to use that.

I have tried SequenceId, but that doesn't seem to care about the Key. It is just global.

Ideally Pulsar would throw away #2 if it came after #1. That is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no since there is no guarantee of the order in which the messages are published to Pulsar. Messages are stored/delivered in the order that Pulsar receives them.

Any solution to this must be done programmatically on the consumer side. One simple approach would be to include a property on each message that represents the desired order, such as sequence id. This would allow the consuming application to reorder the messages on its side.